# How is $e^{\frac{-k(k-1)}{2n}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability, self-learning

I was learning from the book *Introduction to Algorithms (section 5.4.1)* and came across the birthday paradox. This was the solution I saw:

$Pr\{B_k\} = 1. (1 -\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})...(1 - \frac{k-1}{n})$

$1 + x <= e^{x} (Inequality (3.12))$

So from Inequality (3.12), x= $\frac{-1}{n}$

$Pr\{B_k\} \leq  e^{\frac{-1}{n}}e^{\frac{-2}{n}}...e^{\frac{-(k-1)}{n}} $

= $e^{\sum_{i=k}^{k-1}\frac{i}{n}}$

= $e^{\frac{-k(k-1)}{2n}}$

$\leq 1/2$

where n = 365 days and k is the number of people in the room.

Please can anyone explain to me how they end up having $1/2$

Comment: You have
$$e^{-\frac{k(k-1)}{2n}}\leq 1/2 \Leftrightarrow \frac{k(k-1)}{2n}\geq \log 2\Leftrightarrow \frac{k(k-1)}{n}\geq \log 4$$ What are the assumptions on $k$ and $n$?

Comment: @SacAndSac Please why did you put 1/2 there or what made you use 1/2

Comment: @EALehn He is using equivalences. If the first expression is correct, than the second one and then the third one. He put the $1/2$ there from the title of your question. Also, I think the book wants you to solve for $k$ as $n$ is given.

Answer (score 1):

I expect the book is working out how many people have to be in a room for it to be more likely than not that two people in the room have the same birthday. For something to be more likely than not it has to have probability greater than 1/2. That means makes the probability of it not being the case must be less than (1 - 1/2) which is less than 1/2.

Comment: The probability shown in your question is the probability of mutually exclusive birthdays. In other words no shared birthdays. The probability of at least one shared birthday is 1 minus this.

Comment: Alright. Thank you